# Not able to manually partition while Installing Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 along Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation

I have a Windows 10 machine and want to install Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 using a DVD drive but when I boot, at [step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxYyg.jpg), I didn't get the option of `Install Ubuntu alongside windows boot manager`, so I chose `Something else` and clicked <kbd>Continue</kbd>.

In [the next step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB6Eb.jpg) when I select `unusable` and trying to click <kbd>+</kbd>, the <kbd>+</kbd> button is disabled. Similarly, the <kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>Change</kbd> button are disabled as well.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: 17.04 is not supported. Use 16.04 or 18.04 or 18.10 or 19.04.

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, with normal releases being supported for 9 months, and LTS or long-term-support releases being supported for 5 years.  Ubuntu 17.04 from 2017.April was a short-term releases, and is way was EOL, having upgraded to 17.10, then 18.04 LTS etc.  Being EOL (past end-of-life) it's off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for insight @DK Bose. I am new bee in Ubuntu, so after struggling for 2-3 days I posted this question here. Thanks again.

Comment: Using a supported release you're likely to find the same problem so: In Windows disable the Fast Startup feature before booting the Ubuntu installer/live session. Also from Windows you can make rrom for Ubuntu by shrinking one or more partitions.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, you are absolutely correct. Before reading your comment, I just had faced same problem with 16.04 version.

Comment: I have already disabled the fast startup feature in Windows 10 and had shrunk one of my drive. I have partitioned my hard disk in 3 parts 'C', 'D' & 'E'. but nothing is working.

Comment: @DKBose, what you think would work for not 'end of life' Ubuntu version 16.04.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your Windows drive letters are irrelevant to Linux. I think what you are really looking for is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)